.NET Core 6 on docker with https throws certificate related error
I'm trying to run a REST API built on .NET 6 on a Linux Docker eventually. My VS is on Windows 10 and first testing this on the Windows Docker Desktop. Idea is to run this here and import it from the Linux docker.
This is my docker file.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
#EXPOSE 80
#EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./TTKDS.Web/TTKDS.Web.csproj ./TTKDS.Web/
COPY ./TTKDS.Infra/TTKDS.Infra.csproj ./TTKDS.Infra/
COPY ./TTKDS.Core/TTKDS.Core.csproj ./TTKDS.Core/
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore ./TTKDS.Web/TTKDS.Web.csproj --disable-parallel
RUN dotnet build ./TTKDS.Web/TTKDS.Web.csproj  -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish ./TTKDS.Web/TTKDS.Web.csproj  -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

EXPOSE 7245
EXPOSE 7345
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:7245;https://*:7345

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TTKDS.Web.dll"]

Now if I run this with just http as below. Everything works perfectly.
docker run --rm -p 7245:7245 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:7245 ttkds.web:v1

I get neat response both on http://localhost:7245/api/Item/1 and using the up address. This tells me my docker file and the underlying code is behaving properly.
Then I ventured to use the https. Followed this tutorial. Here are the commands I executed in sequence.
PS D:\Projects\TTKDS Core> dotnet dev-certs https --clean
Cleaning HTTPS development certificates from the machine. A prompt might get displayed to confirm the removal of some of the certificates.
HTTPS development certificates successfully removed from the machine.

PS D:\Projects\TTKDS Core> dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p demoapp
The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully.

PS D:\Projects\TTKDS Core> dotnet dev-certs https --trust
Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
Successfully trusted the existing HTTPS certificate.

PS D:\Projects\TTKDS Core> dotnet user-secrets init -p .\TTKDS.Web\TTKDS.Web.csproj
The MSBuild project 'D:\Projects\TTKDS Core\.\TTKDS.Web\TTKDS.Web.csproj' has already been initialized with a UserSecretsId.

PS D:\Projects\TTKDS Core> dotnet user-secrets -p .\TTKDS.Web\TTKDS.Web.csproj set "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password" "demoapp"
Successfully saved Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password = demoapp to the secret store.

Now I ran 2 different commands and got 2 different errors!!
Command 1
PS D:\Projects\TTKDS Core> docker run --rm -it -p 7245:7245 -p 7345:7345 
    -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://*:7345;http://*:7245" 
    -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development 
    -v $env:APPDATA\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets 
    -v $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https/ ttkds.web:v1


Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.

Command 2:
 PS D:\Projects\TTKDS Core> docker run --rm -p 7245:7245 -p 7345:7345 
     -e ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost:7345 
     -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=demoapp 
     -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx 
     -v C:\Users\BVSim\.aspnet\https:/https/  ttkds.web:v1


Unhandled exception.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The certificate data cannot be read with the provided password, the password may be incorrect.
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The certificate data cannot be read with the provided password, the password may be incorrect.

Obviously I'm missing something. I'm not well versed in docker compose yet. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Found it! After 18hours of relentless google search and watching countless youtube videos. The best solution was start from scratch. Youtube algorithm showed this video, which I followed step by step.
Answer for this problem was in two steps :

At 31:50 mark he explains your pfx file should be named in the same name as your library!
And then mentioned to clear localhost certificates from 2 locations in certmgr.
One from Personal > Certificates
Second from Trusted Root Certification Authoriy > Certificates
In my case there were 3 localhost certificates in the TRCA!! One by IIS Express of Visual Studio and two by me I guess.

Another thing I did was to make the password little complex. I read somewhere fleetingly that Windows doesnt like simple passwords! Not sure if that is correct.
Lastly the command to launch the docker container is wrong. Here is the correct command.
 PS D:\Projects\TTKDS Core> docker run --rm -p 7245:80 -p 7345:443 
 -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;http://+" 
 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=d3m04pp 
 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx 
 -v $env:APPDATA\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets 
 -v $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https/ ttkds.web:v1

Now my docker image was running without error and responded on port 7345
